# How do I add recorded times from live data to get total?

Tags: javascript

I am reading in a live value for an angle. If the angle is > 5 then this is considered good. Else it is bad and sends a vibration. I need to measure for each time the angle is bad how many seconds elapse. I have this working. I now also need to create a running total of all the seconds in total the angle is bad over the course of an hour and I have no idea how to achieve this.

```
        if(cal >= 5)
        {
            startTime = new Date().getTime()
            string1 =
            'GOOD!!! :)' 
         displayValue('Angles', string1)
        }

        else
        {   
            endTime = new Date().getTime()
            vibrate1(1500)  
            string2 = 
            'BAD!!! :('
            displayValue('Angles', string2)
        timeDiff = endTime - startTime //in ms
            timeDiff /= 1000
            timeDiff = Math.round(timeDiff)
            displayValue('BadTime', timeDiff)

        }

            function totalTime() {
            timeNow = 0 
            timeNow = timeDiff + timeNow 
            displayValue('Total', timeNow)

    }
```

Comment: I have a function called totalTime() but it just gives me the same output as the else statement.

Comment: Basically, you need an accumulator that will sum up all the 'timeDiff' values you calculate when your angle condition is not met.

Comment: I'm not really understanding how to achieve this though.

Comment: Does it need to be last 60 minutes or would it be ok to start an hour at each clock hour?

Comment: Yes it's fine to start an hour at each clock hour.

Comment: Would be easy to parse a date string to closest hour and use that as an object key like `{'2019-04-04T09:00': {numTimes:3, totalTime:...}`. Then periodically clean up that object removing older times...send to a db etc

Comment: Or make that object property an array and push  new objects to it from your current workflow and do a reduce on the array when you need data. Would be able to calculate longest/shortest period using array also

Comment: Another thing to take into consideration when trying to find a solution is the code is the above if statement is automatically run, so all variables will be reset. So you can't have a global variable to retain the data. Unless LocalStorage or a cookie is used.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to create a variable to hold the overall total, then just add to it.

```
           var total_incorrect = 0;    
           if(cal >= 5)
            {
                startTime = new Date().getTime()
                string1 =
                'GOOD!!! :)' 
             displayValue('Angles', string1)
            }

            else
            {   
                endTime = new Date().getTime()
                vibrate1(1500)  
                string2 = 
                'BAD!!! :('
                displayValue('Angles', string2)
            timeDiff = endTime - startTime //in ms
                timeDiff /= 1000
                timeDiff = Math.round(timeDiff)
                displayValue('BadTime', timeDiff)
                total_incorrect += timeDiff;
            }

                function totalTime() {
                displayValue('Total', total_incorrect)

        }
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. total_incorrect just keeps counting up the seconds and resetting to 0 whenever the condition changes so there is no total.

Comment: @user11012592 if it's resetting then you must be declaring the variable every time the action happens, but you should only be running the if statement every time you are processing the angle.

Comment: The if statement is running continuously. It's live data coming from a sensor that is constantly feeding into the if statement to give feedback on the angle in real time.